# After 30 seconds the info window jumps to logIn window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

when the application runs, it displays an info message with a timer, the timer shows the user, that application is in run and not being frozen. after the timer ends, the app jumps automatically to the next page! how can write the async method with wait 30 seconds? any idea?

XML

```
<Grid>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Text="Thanks alot for your using this app. this is a text application."
                   FontSize="30"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <TextBlock Name="tbTime" FontSize="30"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Code C#

```
public partial class InfoScreen : Window
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer;
                TimeSpan time;
        public InfoScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            JumpToLogIn();
            time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

            timer = new DispatcherTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), DispatcherPriority.Normal, delegate
            {
                tbTime.Text = time.ToString("ss");
                if (time == TimeSpan.Zero) timer.Stop();
                time = time.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1));
            }, Application.Current.Dispatcher);

            timer.Start();
        }
        private async void JumpToLogIn()
        {
            var infopage = new InfoScreen();
            infopage.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61197436/how-to-move-between-two-views-after-three-seconds-in-wpf-c/61197521#61197521)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want the `JumpToLogin()` method to wait 30 seconds before executing, then you can try the following:

```
    private async void JumpToLogIn()
    {
        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        var infopage = new InfoScreen();
        infopage.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Do not declare methods as `async void`, except event handlers. Declare it as `async Task` and await it in an async `Loaded` event handler. Like this, you would call `this.Close();` from inside the InfoScreen constructor.